# Write a program in Java to solve the series

Tags: java, series, factorial

**The series**:

```
S=1+(3/2)!+(5/3)!+(7/4)!…n.
```

n is taken as input from user.

This is the code i used:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Series_4b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a = 1.0, i = 2.0, n = in.nextInt();
        double s = a;
        while ((a/i) < n) {
            a = a + 2;
            i = i + 1;
            s += factorial(a / i);
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    static double factorial(double a) {
        double factorial = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        return factorial;
    }
}
```

This does not work.

**Note**: This is my school project so I can use only BlueJ IDE.

Comment: There are several problems. For instance, you are looping until the sum is greater than n: it doesn't look quite right. Worse, your factorial function is written with the implicit assumption that its argument is an integer. The factorial of a non-integer requires the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). First thing to do would be to make sure your series is correct (and clarify this weird "...n"). Note also that, as is, this series is not convergent.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me how `S` is defined: Does `(3/2)!` mean "`1.5!`", i.e.  `Γ(2.5)`, or is `3/2` meant to be `1` via integer division? What does `...n` mean? But furthermore: what does _"This does not work."_ mean specifically?

Comment: You should provide the project details and what is the logic you took to solve it and what is your expectation!!

Comment: The 's' is the sum of factorial of all integers less than n. Also, (3/2)! means '1.5!' as you stated.

Comment: Your last comment is self-contradictory. You say S is the sum of factorials of **integers**, then you say that you compute (3/2)! as1.5!. Are you aware that 1.5 is **not an integer**?

Comment: Unless you are doing an applied mathematics course, I don't expect that this is what your teacher is actually asking for something involving the Gamma function.  I advise you to check that you have understood the requirements correctly.  Ask your teacher!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, i meant that s is the sum of integers **below** the fraction, for (3/2)! i.e. 1.5! I mean factorial of integers below 1.5 => factorial of 1.   Okay, i think while writing this comment, i got a probable answer to my question, i will try it and inform.

Comment: Well, an unfortunate choice of words, as x! is defined for non-integer x, by x!=Gamma(x+1). So what you mean by (3/2)! is not 1.5! but floor(3/2)!, i.e. the factorial of the (integer) quotient.

Comment: Ok, i understood that i have made a mistake while forming the sentence, moreover i don't have much idea on the gamma function, except for what i have seen in some videos on YouTube ™

Comment: Okay, my teacher updated that it should be a/factorial (i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Series { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    double sum = 1.0;
    int num = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
        num = num + 2;
        double factorial = 1.0;
        for(int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
            factorial = factorial * j;
        }
        sum = sum + (num / factorial);
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the series is: " + sum);
}
}
```

Comment: I want the factorial of the fraction as a whole, not of the denominator only, also i think this is the most problematic part of the whole.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).